# YOLO inferencing crashes when the image does not have target object

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, dotnetnuke

Assume that the YOLO model is trained based on persons. I am using Opencv DNN for inferencing. Then, I use output bounding boxes for further image processing to measure distance.

When I run the inferencing for a road with no target object, let's say no person, the program crashes and gives me an error. Sample image is : [enter link description here](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/118/3/e2024425118/F1.large.jpg?width=800&height=600&carousel=1)

Here is the inferencing:

```
classes, scores, boxes = model.detect(image, CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD, NMS_THRESHOLD)


for (classid, score, box) in zip(classes, scores, boxes):
    color = COLORS[int(classid) % len(COLORS)]
    cv2.rectangle(image, box, color, 2)


# other image processing steps
image, px, py=measurement.original(box,image)
```

**My question is:** When there is no person on the scene, it crashes as it does not find any target object to detect to do the measurements, no bounding box. How do I fix this issue? and return print "target not found" as an output.
Error that I get:

```
File "detection.py", line 72, in <module>
    image, px, py=measurement.original(box,image)
NameError: name 'box' is not defined
```

**PS:** In case there is a bounding box, it returns a value like: [[1251 612 75 79]] but when there is no bounding box it returns nothing, blank

Comment: What is the value of boxes in such a case?

Comment: Good question. In case there is a bounding box, it returns a value like:   [[1251  612  75  79]]   but when there is no bounding box it returns nothing, blank.

Comment: Yeah, that's ideally expected. So I suppose, now you'll be able to solve the issue. Just use an `if` condition check or something like that

Comment: There is no such thing as a variable with a value of nothing or blank, print the value of boxes and put the output here. It is probably an empty list or None.

Comment: as written, I think you're getting red-herringed by python's variable scope. That 'box' variable is scoped to the for loop. When nothing is in the boxes list then the variable isn't actually created because the loop terminates immediately. When there are boxes then the box variable after the for loop is just the last box in the list.